# How to securely isolate databases/users in a multi-tenant Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, security

I want to make a service that gives each of my users their own PG user and database.

Are there any considerations beyond making each person their own user and owner of their own database like this, and letting them connect to the database?

```
create user u2745;
create database d2745 owner u2745;
-- etc.
```

Comment: Typically users are not given direct access to database in a multi-tenant application even if databases are created per user basis.

Comment: This is a platform for developers. Want to provide users direct access to their own provisioned DBs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental problem with that approach if you have few enough tenants. For security reasons, I would `REVOKE` the `CONNECT` privilege on the databases from `PUBLIC`.

The two potential difficulties I see are:

- if you have too many tenants, the catalog tables `pg_authid`, `pg_database` and `pg_shdepend` could grow large, which could make metadata operations unpleasantly slow
- with a different database user per tenant, you cannot easily use a single connection pool (you'd have to use `SET ROLE`), which is usually bad for performance

The big advantage of your setup is that it is very easy to scale horizontally: simply add new machines and run some of the databases there.

If you have many small tenants, row level security might be a better approach.